# How can you move an image left to above the text that was on left side of image

Tags: html, css, image

Here's the code I have.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>.xy{float:right}</style>
</head>
<body>

<img class="xy" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Martinique_Beach_%28Salines%29.jpg" width="250" height="233">

<ul>
<li><h1>abcd&nbsp;eghij&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1></li>
<li><h1>klmn&nbsp;opqr stuw</h1></li>
<li><h1>wxyza bcdef hij&nbsp; klmno&nbsp;</h1></li>
</ul><br><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Widen your browser as far as it will go and then begin to narrow your it and you'll see the text easily flows down the left side of the image. As you narrow your browser farther, eventually all of the text will jump down below the level of the image, leaving a fairly wide white space left of the image where the text was. Once all of the text has jumped down, I need the image to shift left to directly above the text. How do you make the image move left once all the text is below the image w/o media queries?

Don't know why I never saw this problem addressed before

Thanks so much,

Chris

Comment: can you provide some fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `float` on your image like this:

```
<img class="xy" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Martinique_Beach_%28Salines%29.jpg" width="250" height="233" style="float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using bootstrap but another solution to the issue would be

```css
.left{
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<img class="left" src="http://m3.i.pbase.com/g9/50/1212650/3/162837533.B2hScStl.jpg">
<ul class="left">
<li><h1>abcd&nbsp;eghij&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1></li>
<li><h1>klmn&nbsp;opqr stuw</h1></li>
<li><h1>wxyza bcdef hij&nbsp; klmno&nbsp;</h1></li>
</ul><br><br><br><br>
```

if you were using bootstrap classes like `.panel` bootstrap automatically handles scaling on all platforms

Answer (score 0):

### Try This

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .content .xy{
        float:left;
    }
    .content ul{
        float:left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
<img class="xy" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Martinique_Beach_%28Salines%29.jpg" width="250" height="233">

<ul>
    <li><h1>abcd eghij    </h1></li>
    <li><h1>klmn opqr stuw</h1></li>
    <li><h1>wxyza bcdef hij  klmno </h1></li>
</ul><br><br><br><br>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but they didn't seem to work. The third answer I switched the image and text to get the image on the right side, but when narrowing the browser the image dropped down instead of the text.
The second answer kept the image on top and the text on bottom.The first answer kepr the image left. and the text right. The goal is the text on the left and image on the right and as the browser is being narrowed 
the text  flows out of the left side and then straight down below the level of the image, causing the image to immediately shift to the left side.